# Помогите перевести рекурсивный алгоритм в циклический при добавлении AVL дерева

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Вот такой код добавления элемента. Классическая рекурсия и балансировка.

```
node* insert(string x, string y, node* t)
{

    if (t == NULL)
    {

        t = new node;
        t->key = x;
        t->field = y;
        t->height = 0;
        t->left = t->right = NULL;

    }

    else if (x < t->key)

    {

        t->left = insert(x, y, t->left);

        if (height(t->left) - height(t->right) == 2)

        {

            if (x < t->left->key)
                t = singleRightRotate(t);
            else
                t = doubleRightRotate(t);

        }

    }

    else if (x > t->key)

    {
        t->right = insert(x, y, t->right);

        if (height(t->right) - height(t->left) == 2)

        {

            if (x > t->right->key)
                t = singleLeftRotate(t);
            else
                t = doubleLeftRotate(t);

        }

    }

    t->height = max(height(t->left), height(t->right)) + 1;
    return t;
}
```

Проблема в том что при добавлении огромного количества элементов работа программы становится слишком долгой. Цикл, скорее всего, сильно ускорит.

Comment: Очень сомнительно — насчет сильного ускорения только за счет замены рекурсии циклом. Думаю, передача `x` и `y` по ссылке, а не по значению, даст бóльший эффект...

Comment: Вы вообще не заметите разницы между рекурсией и циклом. AVL дерево из миллиона элементов будет иметь высоту 20. Увидеть разницу на двадцати итерациях - надо очень постараться. А то что вы строки копируете (и в случает рекурсии копируете много раз) - это реальная проблема. `const string &` всё ускорит в десятки раз. Вы в профайлер заглядывали? Там конструктор копии строк и менеджер памяти должны экран плавить.